# in python, should the lock thread be initialized before init of the class where critical code happens or after?

Tags: locking

I'm trying to write a program that runs multi processes where at the end of each run, they write stats to a file. My current code looks like this:

```
class Game(tk.Tk):
"""
The main application window.
"""

    def __init__(self, params, width_and_height=750):
        """
        Initialize the application.
        :param params:  list of parameters
        :param width_and_height:  width and height of the application window
        """

        super().__init__()
        self.lock = threading.Lock()



    def save_stats(self):
        """
        Save the stats.csv to a file.
        """
        with self.lock:
            # create dataframe with columns PID, 25 percentile, 50 percentile, 75 percentile and final percentile
            data = {'L value': [self.L_params],
                    'P value': [self.grid.p],
                    'S1 value': [self.grid.s1],
                    'S2 value': [self.grid.s2],
                    'S3 value': [self.grid.s3],
                    'S4 value': [round(1 - self.grid.s1 - self.grid.s2 - self.grid.s3, 2)],
                    '25 percentile': [self.generation_25],
                    '50 percentile': [self.generation_50],
                    '75 percentile': [self.generation_75],
                    'final percentile': [self.percent_received]}
            df = pd.DataFrame(data)

            # write to stats.csv
            df.to_csv('stats.csv', mode='a', header=not os.path.exists('stats.csv'), index=False)
```

however it seems to not work, and my file is filled with incorrect information. Does it make sense to put the lock before the Game class init function so that lock is global?